# What is the best online python tutorial?

Tags: python, tutorial

I would like to learn the basics in a few days during the holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "bucky" and "python" on youtube.  He has some really good tutorials.

Senthil Kumaran's "Solve it with Python" is really good (about 2 hours). You can find it through Miro or it may be on blip.tv.

Maybe one for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Dive in to Python is considered by many to be the best starting resource.

http://diveintopython.org/toc/index.html

Also, I would strongly recommend installing ipython to use as the interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207701/python-tutorial-for-total-beginners

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548334/python-book-tutorial-to-read-after-finishing-with-the-official-tutorial

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418993/python-tutorial-or-reference

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how to program, I'd recommend you consider the [python.org Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html).  As far as quickly getting a feel for the language, I was quite happy with my experience learning Python via it.  It fairly quickly got me up to speed, and from there it was a lot about learning the standard library and what was available there.

If you have specific things you want to do, such as web programming, there may be better books that focus largely on those areas.